# SAS macro output file naming conventions

Tags: sas, filenames, sas-macro

I have a sas macro which is dependent on two varying variables `Age` and `Year` represented by `&Age` and `&Year` respectively.

I want to run the macro for each combination of the ages 15-18 and years 2007-2010 and wish to create an output table for each of these combinations (i.e. 16 tables in total).

Here is my problem, I try to give the output table the following name in the macro `Matrix_pop_adm&Age_RP&Year` which SAS doesn't like.

How can I name my output file correctly ?

Comment: Protip: the best solution isn't having a dataset for each combination, it's using `BY` processing to run the process just once and have just one dataset with all sixteen combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're concatenating macro variables into a string with other delimiting characters, you need to add dots to make each distinct macro variable resolve (in this case) independently.

```
Matrix_pop_adm&Age._RP&Year 
/*                ^ force &AGE to resolve, instead of trying to resolve &Age_RP */
```